# Reference to columns with similar pattern in mutate

Tags: r, pattern-matching, dplyr

I have many columns like pr_1, pr_2, pr_3,.... and I would like to refer to them in `mutate` with `ifelse`
using their similar pattern (or their index), instead of writing all the column names as in below.

```
df<- data.frame(p=c(1,2,3), pr_1=c(1,4,5), pr_2=c(0,1,6), pr_3=c(0,1,4))

df <- df %>% 
 mutate(green=(ifelse(p < pr_1 | p < pr_2 | p < pr_3, 0 , 1)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) cur_data** In dplyr 1.0 we can refer to the current row within `rowwise` using `cur_data()`.  (If the only columns are p and the pr columns and p comes first we could alternately replace the `select` with `cur_data()[-1]`.)

```
df %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(green = +!any(p < select(cur_data(), starts_with("pr")))) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
      p  pr_1  pr_2  pr_3 green
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1     1     1     0     0     1
2     2     4     1     1     0
3     3     5     6     4     0
```

**1a)** or if the values of p are unique and there are no other columns other than p and the pr columns:

```
df %>%
  group_by(p) %>%
  mutate(green = +!any(p < cur_data())) %>%
  ungroup
```

**2) apply** Another approach is to use apply:

```
df %>%
  mutate(green = +!apply(p < select(., starts_with("pr")), 1, any))
```

giving:

```
  p pr_1 pr_2 pr_3 green
1 1    1    0    0     1
2 2    4    1    1     0
3 3    5    6    4     0
```

**3) c_across** We can also use dplyr 1.0 `c_across` .  We have shown how to use `if_else` but we could have used `+!any(...)` as above.

```
df %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(green = if_else(any(p < c_across(starts_with("pr"))), 0, 1)) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
      p  pr_1  pr_2  pr_3 green
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     0     0     1
2     2     4     1     1     0
3     3     5     6     4     0
```

Comment: Thanks! What is the package required for `cur_data` in the first solution? And is there a way to define the green variable with numbers other than zero and one in the first solution?

Comment: dplyr 1.0 or later is needed to use cur_data() . This version should be on CRAN now.    Use if_else(any(...), ...) to return results other than 0 and 1.  See (3) where we use that style.

Answer (score 0):

In base R, you can select the columns with `grep`, compare them with `p` column and use `rowSums`.

```
cols <- grep('pr', names(df))
df$green <- +(rowSums(df$p < df[cols]) == 0)
```